# How would I reuse a random number in ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

I am trying to create a random math equation (just with simple addition) where two random numbers are given to you and you need to add them up. My problem is that the two random numbers used for the answer are different from the ones that are used in the equation

```
puts "Choose the number range (difficulty of the equation)"
difficulty = gets.chomp
a = rand(difficulty)
b = rand(difficulty)
answer = a + b
puts "#{a} + #{b}"
UserAnswer = gets.chomp

if UserAnswer == answer
  puts "good"
else
  puts "bad"
end
```

Comment: That's the problem with random numbers, you never know what you'll get. And that's the entire idea with them too, they're random and you can't guess what they are in advance, otherwise they wouldn't be random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with random numbers. The problem is that you are comparing a number (the sum of the random numbers) with a string (from the user input). You should replace the relevant line with:

```
UserAnswer = gets.to_i
```

By the way, I don't see any reason to use a constant here. It would most likely be better using a local variable like `user_answer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the of a and b in other two variables like a_aux and b_aux, and then refer to these instead of a and b everytime you would use a and b.

Comment: I'm still new at ruby. How exactly would I store the values of a and b into a_aux and b_aux?

Comment: a = rand(difficulty)
a_aux=a
b = rand(difficulty)
b_aux=b

Does this work?

Comment: Why would this help? Perhaps showing some code and explaining why it would help will... er... help.